# non-locally simple $\mathcal{g}$-modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm interested in an example of a simple $\mathcal{g}$-module $M$ over some locally simple Lie algebra say $\mathcal{g}\simeq gl(\infty)$ such that $M$ is not isomorphic to a direct limit of simple finite dimension modules.

Comment: Why not just take a Verma module with a generic highest weight (over, say, $sl_n$)? If the highest weight is generic, this should be a simple, infinite dimensional module, so it has no finite dimensional submodules. (Also

Comment: I want modules not over $sl_n$ but over $sl_{\infty}$. I didn't thought much about Vermas over $sl_{\infty}$ but I doubt they are integrable. 

Comment: @Alex: if you want integrable modules, you should specify it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the finitary simple Lie algebras $L$, like $\mathfrak{sl}(\infty)$,  $\mathfrak{o}(\infty)$, then these locally simple Lie algebras
are known to have no non-trivial finite-dimensional module at all, see the work of Penkov.
In this sense there are many examples. However, if you mean locally simple, i.e., *integrable*
modules of these Lie algebras, then this means that they are the direct limit of simple $L_i$-modules $M_i$.
So we need to find non-integrable modules. 
Given an integrable module $M$, the dual module $M^{\ast}$ is integrable if and only if 
for any $i>0$ $Hom_{L_i}(N,M) = 0$ only for finitely many non-isomorphic simple $L_i$-modules N.
This should give non-integrable modules as dual modules, i.e.,  examples of modules not being a direct limit of finite-dimensional $L_i$-modules.

Comment: I know about the dual module criterion from Penkov's work with Serganova. However the example I was looking for was a simple integrable $\mathfrak{g}$-module $M$ such that it cannot be exhausted by finite dimensional simple modules. But now that I think about it better I guess you can always find a sequence of simple modules at each level and a system of injective morphisms such that $M$ is the direct limit of that sequence with respect to that system.

Comment: A simple integrable module which cannot be exhausted by finite dimensional modules need to be uncountable-dimensional, right ?


Comment: I was under the impression that a simple integrable module has to be countable dimensional. Or can you give me an example of uncountable dimensional simple integrable module? 

Comment: As far as I can tell, your first two sentences answer the question.  If $\mathfrak{g}$ has no nontrivial finite dimensional modules, then any infinite dimensional simple integrable module cannot be a direct sum of finite dimensional simple modules.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @S. Carnahan: the question is not about "direct sum", but "direct limit". Still the question is intriguing, because there is no nontrivial way to make a direct limit of simple modules, unless it means simple modules over simple subalgebras of the Lie algebra or so.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Thank you.  I think I understand now.